# Compare 3 tables in SQL, with result found in A, B, not C

Tags: sql, join, resultset

I am trying to get results from 3 tables, but to show records that reflect
Users from A also in B, but not in C

```
Table A   =   Table B  not in   Table C
-------      --------          --------
UserName     UserName           UserName
```

I apologize if this is too basic. I'm new at this and could not come up with anything from things I googled.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question by providing more information ?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi Esteban, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server (2014)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could do this, one would be by using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Select      *
From        TableA  A
Join        TableB  B   On  A.UserName = B.UserName
Left Join   TableC  C   On  A.UserName = C.UserName
Where       C.UserName Is Null;
```

Another would be by using a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
Select      *
From        TableA  A
Join        TableB  B   On  A.UserName = B.UserName
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    TableC  C
    Where   C.UserName = A.UserName
)
```

Comment: Though I beat you by 2 seconds, I'll conceed because your answer was more robust  +1

Comment: Thank You Siyual. That's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

**Subselect-Solution:**

You could grap them with two subselects with `IN` and `NOT IN` like:

```
SELECT T1.UserName
  FROM Table1 T1
 WHERE T1.UserName     IN (SELECT UserName FROM Table2)
   AND T1.UserName NOT IN (SELECT UserName FROM Table3)
```

**JOIN-Soluction:**

Or you could use `JOINs` like:

```
     SELECT DISTINCT T1.UserName
       FROM Table1 T1
 INNER JOIN Table2 T2
         ON T1.UserName = T2.UserName
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 T3
         ON T1.UserName = T3.UserName
      WHERE T3.UserName IS NULL
```

**EXISTS-Solution:**

If you prefer `EXISTS` you could do like:

```
SELECT T1.UserName
  FROM Table1 T1
 WHERE     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 
                           WHERE T1.UserName = T2.UserName)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table3 T3 
                           WHERE T1.UserName = T3.UserName)
```

Comment: Thank You Esteban this is great !